# I'm getting Georgia or Georgia-like on my blog when I don't want it wondering if wp-includes has been modified by a plugin

Tags: theme-twenty-fourteen

I'm trying to just use Lato which is used in twenty fourteen which is what is active in my http://janet.tokerud.com blog but getting something I used to use that doesn't fit this new theme.

Thinking maybe when I did whatever I did - I think used a plug-in to get one the google fonts to show that it permanently changed something on the backend that is forcing this font to be used for body text in the blog post. Sorry I'm tech savvy but not a CSS professional or WordPress professional so I may be naming these things wrong.

***PROBLEM RESOLVED THANKS!*** See my comment below.

Comment: It is going to be difficult to guess "whatever you did". Unless you've hacked Twenty Fourteen or the WordPress Core, it must be a plugin. Disable them one by one and see if you can isolate the issue.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping on this. I fiddled with the edit css and finally used the p style there and that overrode the font that was a problem. So I'm going to call it a day on this. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

How to use google fonts in your theme:

1. Go to google fonts and find your font. Once your have found your font click on the second icon (paper -> arrow) that says "Quick Use" when you mouse over.
2. You now have a page that shows how to use your font. Look at section 3 of that page. Click on the tab called "@import" Copy that code. In your case:

   @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);
3. Located your style.css file either by browsing your website via FTP or by going to Theme editor inside the WP Admin.
4. Add the code above towards the top of your style.css. You should add it after the file comments (template name, author name and so on).
5. Now let's say you want all your paragraphs to use that font. Find the "p" selector in your style.css file and add the style below:

   p {
            font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
       }

Now the lato font will be applied to all paragraphs on your website. If you want the lato font to be applied just to the main page/post paragraph you can do something similar to this:

```
.entry-content p{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

You should spend sometime reading about CSS selectors. It will help you to get a lot done in your website.

Comment: Thanks for educating me on this gdaniel. You rock. I agree with your advice and will try to learn more about selectors!